# Use R 'sample' function to make a table from a vector

Tags: r, sample, names

I'm fairly new to R/RStudio which I use for learning bioinformatics. I am working through the 'Introduction to R' in this online course https://uclouvain-cbio.github.io/WSBIM1207/sec-startr.html

Here is my SessionInfo() in RStudio:
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Using an old Mac laptop temporarily hence the outdated R and MacOS versions.

The question is:
'Using the sample function, simulate a set of 100 students voting (randomly) for 1, 2 or 3 breaks during the WSBIM1207 course.'
Here is the code I used, which worked:

```
sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)
```

The next question is the one I don't know how to solve:
'Display the values as a table of votes.'
I tried using the 'names' function since that can generate a table-like output but could not get that to work.
I don't think the answer requires other functions in R as that would be outside the scope of this 'Introduction to R' course chapter. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: `table`, `table`.

Comment: `vote <- sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE)`. Using `table(vote)` will return the table your looking for. As an improvement, the `tabyl` function from `janitor` package is more complete and offers more customization, have a [look](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/janitor/index.html)

Comment: Your first solution solved my problem. Great.